# cannot build with compatibility above 20

Tags: cuda, compatibility

I am using vs2010, cuda6.5. When I specify

```
compute_20,sm_20
```

in project **Properties -> CUDA C/C++ ->Device**, the code builds with no problem.
However, when I designate two more compatibility like following:

```
compute_20,sm_20
compute_35,sm_35
compute_52,sm_52
```

The build fails, and gives following error message:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 6.5.targets(593,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=\"sm_35,compute_35\" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=\"sm_35,compute_35\" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"  -IC:\FAWKESBASE\Release\INC -IC:\FAWKESBASE\Release\INC -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include"     --keep-dir x64\Release -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static     -D_WINDLL -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /Zi  /MD  " -o x64\Release\FilterSino.cu.obj "D:\SW_ImageChan_64Slice\RecCWinLibAxial64\FilterSino.cu"" exited with code 1.
1>
```

I tried 35 and 52, both failed. It seems as long as the compatibility is higher than 20, it fails. Anyone has a pointer? Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE:**

Looks like it says:

```
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_52'
```

So can I support 52 at this time? Is this a vs2010 problem or a cuda6.5 problem? I have a card that is compatible with 52, that is why I added this option in my build.

Comment: Could you posted the actual nvcc error? What you have shown from Visual Studio is completely unhelpful

Comment: @talonmies Where and how do I get complete nvcc error please?

Comment: @talonmies see update. Looks like 52 is not supported?

Comment: That is what the compiler is explicitly telling you.

Comment: @talonmies Thanks!

Comment: @talonmies can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first release of CUDA 6.5 doesn't support compute capability 5.2 or newer devices. NVIDIA released an [updated version of 6.](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads-geforce-gtx9xx)5 with support for the GT9xx family of GPUs (sm_52 architecture) which you could try, otherwise you need to install CUDA 7.0 or newer to compile for that architecture.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link!